# get the position of image after shuffle list of Imageview array

Tags: android

```
int[] images2 = {
            R.drawable.wrong, R.drawable.reviewp,
            R.drawable.bowl, R.drawable.ic_action_search
            };
List<int[]> pic=Arrays.asList(images2);
Collections.shuffle(pic);
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++){

    ReciverI[i].setBackgroundResource(images2[ "at here i want to get the image position"   ]);
    }
```

help me to get the position of image

this is not working

```
    ReciverI[i].setBackgroundResource(images2[Integer.parseInt(pic.get(i).toString())]);
```

this give me wrong result

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more. What position do you want to get? Why are you not giving i itself?

Comment: i want to get 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite the code

**Solution 1**

```
Integer[] images2 = {R.drawable.wrong, R.drawable.reviewp, R.drawable.bowl,R.drawable.ic_action_search};
List<Integer> pic=Arrays.asList(images2);
Collections.shuffle(pic);
for(int i = 0 ; i <= pic.size() ; i++){
ReciverI[i].setBackgroundResource(pic.get(i))
}
```

You want absolutely to conserve the primitiv int then you have to make a little walk around

**Solution 2**

```
List<Integer> pic = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 0; index < images2.length; index++)
        {
            pic.add(images2[index]);
        } 
        Collections.shuffle(pic);
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= pic.size() ; i++){
          ReciverI[i].setBackgroundResource(pic.get(i))
        }
```

Comment: The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Comment: @Rohit just change int[] to Integer[] and everything will be okay!

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer[]>

Comment: @Rohit which one are using? solution 1 or 2 i test both and everything is correct

Comment: @Rohit please make sure that you do everything as i do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26087/discussion-between-festus-tamakloe-and-rohit)

Comment: i am accepting answer, but my boss give me the solution, the problem was at another place, actually i was generating all things at run time and doing drag and drop in android 2.2, now my problem is solved by my boss, thanks for your precious time....god bless you

Comment: @Rohit you're welcome. We've to resolve the problem as you explain it to us. Thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

```
ReciverI[i].setBackgroundResource(pic.get(i))
```

Sorry wasn't paying attention. You should just make your `List<int>` and it will work.
As your snippet is now, it has no use to have a List of integer arrays.

Comment: The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int[]);


this error shown

Comment: Because you're passing your whole integer array, instead of 1 int. Just make your List<int> instead.

Comment: please do it, m totally confused, m doing from morning this is not working

Comment: List<int> pic=Arrays.asList(images2);

Comment: i am using this , what you change in it

Comment: Dude, last comment. Look at your code closely. You are using List<int[]> , not List<int>. It's a big difference. Good luck.

Comment: now this error shown on int ; Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26086/discussion-between-rohit-and-stefan-de-bruijn)

Comment: i vote up for your result, my problem solved my boss, thanks a lot